# Using a token from `googleAuthR` in `googlesheets`

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny, google-authentication

The `googleAuthR` is an R package which wraps the google API client library (authentication and further usage of the API). The `googlesheets` R package is used to integrate with the google sheets API (i.e., a wrapper around the google sheets API).

Each of these packages has a seperate OAuth2.0 process of their own. I'm using the `googleAuthR` in order to log into a shiny app, which in turn also uses the `googlesheets` library (but with a different authentication process).

**The question:** How can we set the `googlesheets` package to use the initial `googleAuthR` credentials as well?

Here is the process I'm using (within a shiny app):

For the `googleAuthR` login I'm using:

```
options(googleAuthR.webapp.client_secret = "***REMOVED_FROM_EXAMPLE***")
options(googleAuthR.webapp.client_id = "***REMOVED_FROM_EXAMPLE***")
options(googleAuthR.scopes.selected = c("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
                                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"))
```

And for the `googlesheets` package, I'm currently using a pre-registered (separate) token which I saved into an RDS file, as suggested in the package's vignette:

```
suppressMessages(gs_auth(token = "googlesheets_token.rds", verbose = FALSE))
gsheet_log <- googlesheets::gs_url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/***REMOVED_FROM_EXAMPLE***/edit#gid=0")
```

I would like a flow which replaces the use of `gs_auth` with the token generated by `googleAuthR`.

**IMPORTANT NOTE** (Added to this question at a later time):

I think that perhaps the use of `googlesheets` is relevant only for the short term and **should be discouraged**, because google are going to deprecate it on March 3, 2020 [see message](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3)

Hence @Aurèle's comment might be the way to go here (hoping that `googlesheets4` will get, eventually, all the capabilities of its predecessor). The question might still be interesting in the broader sense.

Comment: Consider the (not yet on CRAN) successor `googlesheets4` https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4 , that relies on `gargle` for auth (on CRAN, https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/gargle/index.html )

Comment: Thanks, but at this point in time googlesheets4 doesn't have a lot of the capabilities of googlesheets, e.g., adding a single row to an existing sheet.

Comment: A workaround that I did was to download the files using the `googledrive` package, then read the file in using `readxl` or `readr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have struggled myself to authenticate via `googleAuthR` and then use my credentials to read a sheet using `googlesheets4` library. Unfortunately, I still cannot make it work, but I found a crude workaround in "pure" `googleAuthR`. Using `gar_api_generator` function you can actually call any requests that is allowed in Google API.

```
library(shiny)
library(googleAuthR)
options(shiny.port = 8787)
options(googleAuthR.redirect = "http://localhost:8787")

# JSON with you client data from GCP
gar_set_client(scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
               web_json = "<YOUR_JSON>")
spreadsheet_key <- "<YOUR SHEET>"

read_googlesheet <- gar_api_generator(
  baseURI = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/",
  http_header = 'GET',
  path_args = list(spreadsheets = spreadsheet_key,
                   values = "A:U"), #column range 
  data_parse_function = function(x) x$values
)

## ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(title = "googleAuthR Shiny Demo",
                tableOutput("gs")
)

## server.R
server <- function(input, output, session){
  gar_shiny_auth(session)

  output$gs <- renderTable({
    df_raw <- read_googlesheet()
    # make the first row of the dataset as a header
    df <- df_raw[c(2:nrow(df_raw)), ]
    colnames(df) <- df_raw[1, ]
    df
  })
}

shinyApp(gar_shiny_ui(ui, login_ui = gar_shiny_login_ui), server)
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try using service account token instead for authentication? https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/get-api-credentials.html

Might be a little tedious at first to set up but it was worth it for me

1. Go to console.cloud.google.com
2. Add project
3. Create credential and download json
4. Enable API (google sheets)
5. Copy the address of the "new credential" and go to the google sheet you want to access/manipulate (add user)

```
library(googlesheets4)

sheets_auth(path = "/path/to/a/service-account.json")
df <- read_sheet(ss = "sheet_key_here")
df
```

Comment: There are some cases when you cannot use API key (e.g. access a non-public sheet).